# PHP set include path is not working on Ubuntu linux

Tags: php

I developed a website on WampServer in windows. After finishing the site and testing all the features I tried to deploy it on linux server running Ubuntu. I started to get errors about not found files which were not found in my include path ! I set the include path in htaccess file, same php file and even php.ini with absolute path and no luck it doesn't work. I tried to check the cases of the required files but they were correct !
I am not sure what is the problem so can any one help me debugging this issue !

Comment: What is the include_path and the required files you are trying to include?

Comment: Please post some lines from your configuration.

Comment: if you dont show us anything we won't be able to help you in the right direction, try posting the errros youre getting for a start and what you have add to htaccess file aswell as were those files are in your current domain folder.

Comment: put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a `.php` file, deploy that to your webhost and request it in a browser. Find the `include_path` line and paste it as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: You are using `php_value` settings to specify the include path, but unlike on the Windows server, PHP is not running as an Apache module on your Ubuntu install which is a [prerequisite for those .htaccess settings to work](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check the separator between the paths. Windows uses `;` (semicolon) and Linux uses `:` (colon). You also need to make sure you are using forward slashes between directories in each path on Linux instead of backslashes.

`c:\include;c:\include\path;.` --> `/include:/include/path:.`

Another possibility is that the user running Apache does not have read access to the include directory.